# Getting data from a chart from a website using python

Tags: python-3.x, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I was making a project and I asked myself a question: is it possible to get the data (or the whole graph) from a site that generates it with javascript (or any other programming language)? The site I'm interested in [is this one](https://coinmarketcap.com/currencies/bitcoin/).... Thanks in advance..

Comment: Hi, welcome to stackoverflow. Please read the guidelines on how to write a good question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and rewrite the question.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can, by using those two libraries:

```
from urllib.request import urlopen
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
```

The urllib.request module is used to open URLs. The Beautiful Soup package is used to extract data from html files.

Comment: Just one thing... isn't urllib.request the same as requests?

Comment: Requests is not a native library. If you are ok with adding dependencies, then requests is fine. However, if you are trying to avoid adding dependencies, urllib is a native python library that is already available to you. They are both an options. At the end of the day It comes to whatever you prefer.

Comment: I noticed that, in one section of the web page I linked to, there is a button with a "camera" that provides the link to the graph image. is there any way to get there? Trying with bs4 tells me it is not available....

Comment: If you are using Linux, simply install it by: apt-get install python3-bs4. for the image part, use urllib.request.urlretrieve() and PIL.Image.open().